# Why does Scala require partial application of curried functions when assigning to a val?

Tags: scala, currying

In Scala, why is it that a curried function can easily be passed directly to other functions, but when assigning it to a `val` one needs to also partially apply it with `_`?  For example, given the two functions:

```
def curried(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
def test(a: Int, f: Int => Int) = f(a)
```

I can easily pass `curried` to `test` with:

```
test(5, curried(5))
```

and everything is happy. However if I simply call `curried(5)` I get an error:

```
scala> curried(5)
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method curried;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              curried(5)
```

If I change the call to include type information however, it works:

```
val 'curried: Int => Int = curried(5)
```

Can anyone explain the rational behind the inconsistency, surely the Scala compiler can infer that the function is `Int => Int` given the type definition on the original method?

Comment: In the `val` case if you give a type annotation you won't need the overt partial application `_`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not inferring the type, the problem is inferring your intent. Did you make a mistake, or did you intentionally curry the function?

Alas, the trailing underscore syntax is the formal syntax, and omitting it is syntactical sugar.

Comment: That makes sense, but surely the fact I _declared_ the method as a curried function described my intent already. If the problem is in inferring intent, why is it ok for inlining?

Comment: @MarkDerricutt I'm not sure what you mean by "inlining", but in all cases you've shown where it works you _declared_ what you expected it to be, so Scala goes ahead with currying because it matches your expectation. As for the former, Scala doesn't curry implicitly, it curries explicitly with trailing underscore or if types match -- if you come from a language with implicit currying that might seem unnatural. The function _declaration_, however, declares multiple parameter lists, which is useful for other things than currying.

Comment: By "inlining" I was meaning the use in the argument position ( thinking about it tho, the assignment to the argument has fully qualified type information, so is essentially the same as my last example).

I had assumed Scala explicit currying to come from the multiple argument lists, unlike Haskell's approach where every method declaration is implicitly curried, and any call with missing args just returns the curried function at that position.

My confusion comes from the assumption that "multiple parameter lists == currying", obviously this is not specifically the case.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore isn't always needed. From http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/

```
val zscore = (mean:R, sd:R) => (x:R) => (x-mean)/sd
```

currying, obvious syntax.

```
def zscore(mean:R, sd:R) = (x:R) => (x-mean)/sd
```

currying, obvious syntax

```
def zscore(mean:R, sd:R)(x:R) = (x-mean)/sd
```

currying, sugar syntax. but then:

```
val normer = zscore(7, 0.4) _
```

**need trailing underscore to get the partial, only for the sugar version.**